# AddBlobData(Encoding.GetBytes(string)) Only grabbing first Character

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-component

I have been trying to assign/append a string to a blob column in an output buffer, on a C# script that's taking a number of input rows, and concatenating them where the related id is identical, passing onto the next row where the is new, and seem to be coming up against a problem that may be me not knowing the intermediate steps.

I'm using this:

```cs
Output0Buffer.compAlert.AddBlobData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(alert),alert.Length);
```

To assign the alert string to the `NTEXT` column `compAlert`.

The theory and what I can see from previous answers is that this will add the string alert to said `NTEXT` column. The issue I'm coming across is this only adds the first character of that string. As near as I can tell, if GetBytes is fed a string, it should iterate over that string and add everything? I appear to be missing something that all the other answers that say to use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` are taking for granted that I don't know that should be done?

Comment: Aside from anything else, `alert.Length` is the number of *characters* in the string - whereas `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` will return twice as many *bytes*. I suggest you call the overload that only has a single parameter (assuming I'm looking at the docs for the right AddBlobData method).

Comment: @JonSkeet there is two overloads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.blobcolumn.addblobdata?view=sqlserver-2019#microsoft-sqlserver-dts-pipeline-blobcolumn-addblobdata(system-byte()-system-int32)

Comment: @Hadi: That was the page I was looking at - it just wasn't entirely clear to me based on the tags whether that was the type involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.blobcolumn.addblobdata?view=sqlserver-2019), the `count` argument in the `public void AddBlobData (byte[] data, int count)` method refers to :

> The number of bytes of binary data to be appended.

You should use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(alert).length` instead of `alert.length`.

```cs
Output0Buffer.compAlert.AddBlobData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(alert),Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(alert).Length);
```

Or simply use:

```
Output0Buffer.compAlert.AddBlobData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(alert));
```